# How to prevent interface flipping in GTK 2.16 for right-to-left languages (Arabic, Farsi)?

Tags: gtk, arabic, right-to-left, farsi, gtk-windows

For programs using the GTK 2.16 interface, GTK automatically chooses the language for common items according to system settings, and when the language is right-to-left it automatically flips the interface so that it looks right-to-left. Unfortunately this is not good for programs that were written to appear in left-to-right English language.

What can I do to make gtk2 interface left-to-right? In another words I don't want GTK detect my language, I want to set it to English. I don't want it to automatically flip the programs' interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the LANG environment variable seems to help. Either open a CMD, do `set lang=en` and then run the app (from within this CMD), or change the environment variable via the Control Panel (for all apps).